# How can I use results from query in c# script in visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I want to run a query in a C# script in visual studio and use the results in my C# code (what I basically want to do is to store the results of the query in a table and use the elements in this table one by one).

The query looks like this in my C# script:

```
string Connection_sheets = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection_sheets))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct [Sheet Code] from cell where [Table Code] = 'Table Number' order by [Sheet Code] asc", connection);
    SqlDataReader readert = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 }
```

Here 'Table Number' is a string which comes from a column in another database table.

In the following code, which is placed  in a for loop, I want to add another column where I print each time a single element from the resulting query

```
DataRow newRow2 = _longDataTable.NewRow();
newRow2.ItemArray = drlibrary.ItemArray;

newRow2["VariableTableCode"] = tableName;
newRow2["VariableRowCode"] = ssRowNoBars;
newRow2["VariableColumnCode"] = ssColumnNoBars;

_longDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow2);
```

Anyone an idea how to do this?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: need a bit more detail here mate + put your full method in here in 1 code snippet. Splitting it up is hard to understand your problem..

Comment: Does both datatable belong to the same database?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Some more details: I can run the query and it returns for example G1, G2, G3 and G4. Now I want to add these values to a new column in a different table each on a seperate row using  the DataRow newRow2.

Comment: The table to which I want to add the values is made using the newRow2 datarows in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Within your using statement add

```
While(reader.read()){

DataRow datarow3= _longDataTable.NewRow();
  datarow3.ItemArray = drlibrary.ItemArray;

   datarow3["VariableTableCode"] = reader.tostring(0);
   datarow3["VariableRowCode"] = reader.tostring(1);
   datarow4["VariableColumnCode"] = reader.tostring(2);

    _longDataTable.Rows.Add(datarow3);
       // you may need to encrement the row name variable. 

   }
```

Comment: This prints the results of the query in the three given columns right? I want these columns to stay the same and have values ssRowNoBars and ssColumnNoBars as these values are made using huge if statements. I want to add another column with the query results here

Comment: Could you maybe also explain the 0, 1 and 2 indices in reader.tostring

Comment: So the 0,1,2 are the column index of each row. So for each row it gets item 1,2,3.. and so on. It’s 0 indexed. To add a new Column u should just need to add another reader.tostring() line. Given that the database has another column. Otherwise define it explicitly